# excel vba copy block of cells and insert multiple times

Tags: excel, vba, insert, user-input, messagebox

I'm trying to copy a template block of cells, then have it insert into the row the user selects. Ideally I'd want the code to copy the template block then drop down 2 rows, insert the block X number of times , where X is the number of blocks the user needs. X would be the result of a inputbox. Then after each block is inserted, open the the replace text window. 
IF someone can help me get the existing code to insert the template block multiple times via an input box that would be a huge help. If the find and replace works in full that would be even better

here is my code so far.

```
    Sub CopyTemplate()

Worksheets("HR-Cal").Activate
Dim rng As Range
Dim trng As Range
Dim tco As String
'Use the InputBox select row to insert copied cells
Set rng = Application.InputBox("select row to paste into", Default:=ActiveCell.Address, Type:=8)

startrow = rng.Row
'  MsgBox "row =" & startrow
Range("AF2") = startrow

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'copy template block
Range("C6").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=ROW(RC[-1])"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Cut
Range("AF1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste

tco = "A5:AL" & Range("af1")
Range(tco).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A" & Range("af2")).Activate
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'find and replace text
Dim Told As String
Dim Tnew As String
Dim rep As Range


'Use the InputBox to select text to be replaced
Set rep = Application.InputBox("select data that needs text replaced", Default:=ActiveCell.Address, Type:=8)
    Told = Application.InputBox("Find the following text", Default:=ActiveCell.Address, Type:=1)
    Tnew = Application.InputBox("Input desired text", Default:=ActiveCell.Address, Type:=1)
    rep.Select
        Selection.Replace What:=Told, Replacement:=Tnew, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False


End Sub
```

Comment: Is the block constant?

Comment: it can vary in size. but it always starts in row 5. In my code I can found a work around for this. everything above the input box works fine to grab the block (usually 20-50 rows long). The part that isn't working is having the user select a row to insert the copied cells / have the code drop the block in X number of times, x being input by the user via a message box.

Comment: Have you resolved this yet?

Comment: For the most part yes, I got the basic version of this to work with a few helper cells. I haven't found a way to get the find/replace to work just yet. The code above contains the what I have so far, including find and replace code that throws up an error

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: @findwindow if you run the code above it will ask you to select area to replace text, then type in old data / text to be replaced. Then it asks for text you want in place of old text. After that when it should replace the text I get " run time '1004' : method of 'range' of object'_Global' failed " at the line `range(rep).select`

Comment: Hmmm perhaps try `rep.select`?

Comment: @findwindow That worked perfectly thank you. I will update the code above to show that correction.